# "No matter (what?) the cost"

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis

What is the correct saying?

> No matter the cost

vs

> No matter what the cost

As in, "I have to do this no matter the cost"?

Comment: It is a saying, usually "no matter the cost", but there are many variations: regardless of the cost, at any cost, at all costs.  It would not be incorrect to use "no matter what the cost".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, however the first is more popular (see [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+matter+the+cost%2Cwhatever+the+cost%2Cno+matter+what+the+cost%2Cat+any+cost%2Cregardless+of+the+cost%2Cat+all+costs&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cno%20matter%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bno%20matter%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNo%20matter%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwhatever%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhatever%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhatever%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cno%20matter%20what%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bno%20matter%20what%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNo%20matter%20what%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cat%20any%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20any%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20any%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cregardless%20of%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bregardless%20of%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRegardless%20of%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cat%20all%20costs%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20all%20costs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20all%20costs%3B%2Cc0))

There are other possible variants: **at all costs**, **at any cost**, **whatever the cost**, **regardless of the cost**.